# Dafny installation on openSUSE leap 15.0

Tags: dafny

I am trying to install dafny on my laptop, which runs openSUSE leap 15.0 as OS. Since there is no openSUSE version on https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/releases

I hoped that `dafny-2.1.1.10209-x64-ubuntu-14.04.zip`
might do the trick. But, it did not.

When I run mono `path/Dafny.exe example.dfy` I get the prompt `Dafny 2.1.1.10209`
but otherwise a black window.

`mono --trace` shows that the programs stops somewhere in the middle without warning.

Does this mean I am out of luck with my OS or is there a way to succeed?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using VS Code? It will give you an interactive Dafny experience, which is far better than the command line. The Dafny plug-in for VS Code will also install Dafny for you. I don't know if this will solve the actual problem you're having, but it would be worth trying.

Comment: Thanks Rustan, I started to give VS Code a try. But I need to get hold of

Comment: Please, ignore the second half of my last comment. I could install the downloaded .rpm file only after turning of signature verification. I guess that is OK.